# bash script shell input

Tags: bash

I am currently writing a bash script and when i run the useradd command it requires 2x input. What is the command to input from the bash script into the prompted password fields from useradd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is being read from stdin, you could do this;

```
useradd <<EOF
first input
second input
EOF
```

Some programs, however, do not read from stdin precisely to stop this kind of thing.

**Edit**

As remarked upon, this is called a "HERE document", in case you want to look it up.

Comment: For the benefit of the author of th question, this is called a 'Here Document', in case you want to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

try using [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/):

> Expect is a tool for automating interactive applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc

expect works also for programs that do not read from stdin.

Comment: I should have recalled that. I have used except for this precise reasons tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be bothered booting up my Linux system to check, but does the useradd program still prompt if you pass the information on the command line?

```
useradd -m -p encryptedPassword username
```